# Get excel cell's value as text epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a excel file with a column with format like this
[image]

when i tried to get cell value by

```
var v = cell.Value;
```

it return Double, so how can i get value as text ?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the cell value back to a DateTime object. Then you can format it any way you want.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate((double)cell.Value);
string dateFormatted = date.ToLongDateString();
```